# Guardar caché descargado en JSON en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, json, cache

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con Volley que lee un JSON en línea para obtener los datos, uno de los datos es una imagen alojada en un servidor.

El caso es que si la conexión no es demasiado buena el tiempo de descarga de los datos se vuelve demasiado largo, y me gustaría hacer algo similar al caché web, que pudiera visualizar los datos (fotografía incluida) sin necesidad de descargarlo cada vez que se accede a la aplicación, y que solo se renovasen si el JSON web y los datos locales fueran distintos.

```
    public void jsoncall() {


    ArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_JSON, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;


            for (int i = 0 ; i<response.length();i++) {

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Anime anime = new Anime();

                    anime.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    anime.setGif(jsonObject.getString("gif"));
                    anime.setImage_url(jsonObject.getString("comb"));
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,anime.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    lstAnime.add(anime);
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            //    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Size of Liste "+String.valueOf(lstAnime.size()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,lstAnime.get(1).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            setRvadapter(lstAnime);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
```

Cabe alguna posibilidad de hacer algo parecido?

Gracias!

Comment: Hola Marcia, agrega el código que has tratado para tener una idea de como apoyarte :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi parecer tienes 3 opciones:

1.- Puedes guardar el JSON en base de datos SQlite

2.- Puedes guardar el JSON en SharedPreferences

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder().create();

SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_CLIENT, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("JSON_KEY", builder.toJson(object)); 
editor.commit();
```

3.- Puedes guardar en cache con estos 3 metodos puedes guardar, obtener y verificar si existe

```
public void toCache(String url, String content) {
        File dir = _context.getCacheDir();
        File tempFile = new File(dir.getPath() + "/" + url.replace("/", "_"));
        FileWriter writer;
        try {
            if (tempFile.exists()) {
                tempFile.delete();
                tempFile.createNewFile();
            }
            writer = new FileWriter(tempFile);
            writer.write(content);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String fromCache(String url) {
        String content = "";
        File dir = _context.getCacheDir();
        File tempFile = new File(dir.getPath() + "/" + url.replace("/", "_"));
        FileReader fReader;
        try {
            fReader = new FileReader(tempFile);
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);
            String strLine = "";
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            while ((strLine = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(strLine + "\n");
            }
            fReader.close();
            content = text.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;
    }

    public boolean inCache(String url) {
        File dir = _context.getCacheDir();
        File tempFile = new File(dir.getPath() + "/" + url.replace("/", "_"));
        if (tempFile.exists()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

En cuento a las imagenes de recomiendo que las cargues con Glide es una muy buena libreria para manejo de imagenes y te permite cachear igual.

```
GlideApp  
    .with(context)
      .load("URL DE LA IMAGEN")
      .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
      .into(imageView3);
```

Mas informacion puedes encontrar en su documentacion:
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics

Comment: ¿Como se realizaría con Volley? y lo más importante que se descargue si el JSON web y los datos locales fueran distintos.

Comment: Con volley lo mismo, una vez q tienes la respuesta del servidor lo que tienes es un JSON, y lo puedes guardar con nombre de fecha hora minuto (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss), esto para comparar con lo que tienes en cache si la hora del dato guardado es menor al nuevo dato lo reemplazas y listo.No olviden votar la respuesta :D

Comment: aunque se guarde con la fecha y hora, cuando lo pidas nuevamente ambos archivos pueden tener la misma información, entonces la fecha y hora será diferente y se reemplazaría aunque internamente no cambie la información.

Comment: En ese caso en tu servicio debes enviar un parametro de la fecha y hora de la ultima actualización. Por ejemplo, si tienes un servicio que trae clientes y el servicio te envia 2000 clientes, la proxima vez que solicites el servicio como enviaras el parametro de fecha y hora de actualización, ya el servicio no te enviara los 2000 clientes solo enviara los clientes que se hayan actualizado o nuevos clientes a apartir de la fecha y hora que le envies, asi evitas traer datos que no sean con la misma información

Comment: ¿pero como se enviaría la fecha, tienes un ejemplo?

Comment: Simplemente en el GET de tu servicio le aumentas el parametro por ejemplo si usas REST seria algo asi http://localhost/Proyecto/obtenerDatos/2018-08-01 10:15:30, ahora en el servicio simplemente lo obtienes y puedes usar el parametro

Comment: Creo que me decantaría por la opción 1 o 2.... Realmente uso 4 archivos JSON pero tengo una idea que quiero que me la apruebes como viable si puede ser. Mi idea es crear un archivo JSON para ÚNICAMENTE guardar la versión en la que están los datos (1, 2, 3, 4..) y guardar esto en SQL o sharedPreferences. Al descargar por primera vez el JSON guardaría los datos en columnas en SQLite para tratarlo después como una BDD, y cada vez que se conecte comprobaría la versión del JSON, y si es mayor de la que tengo descargar y reemplazar. Es viable con Volley montar algo así?

Comment: Claro es viable igual con Volley como se le indico mas arriba en los comentarios a Jorgesys